# Best number of server (queuing theory)

Tags: queueing-theory

Is it possible to determine the best number of servers for an MMc queuing system, knowing only the arrival and service rates, ie without knowing the costs involved?

Thank you!

Comment: Would does "best" mean when you don't know the costs?

Comment: @QQQ I want to know if using the server utilization (rho) or the average time (W/Wq) or the average clients (L/Lq), I can determine the number of servers that require to be efficient. I do not know the total cost of the service or the total cost of waiting time

Comment: Again, what is efficient? The more servers you have the  shorter the queues and waiting times will be. So you need to assume a cost for servers or some capacity constraint for the question to be meaningful.